# Tableview scroll changes selection

Tags: ios, swift

i looked at a couple of StackOverflow questions related with this one but it seems in not getting yet the concept very well.

I have a tableview with a couple of cells that i fill using a enum. When i scroll down the rows another row lower in the table gets selected. I have the following methods implemented:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("activityCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = activities[indexPath.item].rawValue;

    return cell;
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    var cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath);
    cell?.selected = true;

}
```

I understand that the cells are reusable but i was not able to understand properly this concept and how it applies.

Can you give me some help?

Cheers

Comment: So is the problem that multiple cells are being selected upon scrolling up in your table when you don't intend them to be?

Comment: A type of 'selectedCells' array holding the index of selected cells... Then as the method cellForRowAtIndexPath is called, it can check if that index is in the array and thus set the cell as selected.. First thought that came to mind :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to reuse your cells, setting the cell as `selected` in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` at indexPath in the way that you've done will make the reused cell's also reflect the changed `selected` property. Instead, I'd recommend adding a boolean `selected` property to your activity object such that the selection changes can be made in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, ex:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("activityCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = activities[indexPath.item].rawValue
    cell?.selected = activities[indexPath.item].selected
    return cell;
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    activities[indexPath.item].selected = true
    self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    activities[indexPath.item].selected = false
    self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)

}
```

Comment: Thank you Lyndsey that helped a lot.

Comment: @FilipeLouro Glad to hear :)

Answer (score 0):

> As Byron suggested, we can handle this scenario by saving the selected
>   index paths in an array and removing them from array when unselected.

```
var indexArray  : [NSIndexPath]?
```

> Initialise the indexArray before loading the table as

```
self.indexArray = []
```

> Cell selection & de-selection must be reflected in the indexArray with the help of delegate functions as:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath) {
                cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
                self.indexArray?.append(indexPath as NSIndexPath)
        }
       }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath) {
            cell.accessoryType = .none
            if let pos = self.indexArray?.index(of: indexPath as NSIndexPath)
            {
                self.indexArray?.remove(at: pos)
            }
        }
       }
```

> Now, when **cellForRowAtIndexpath** function gets called for each row, check whether the current indexPath is present in our indexArray. If so, the cell is already selected, else, the cell is in unselected state & perform corresponding tasks on the cell.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "yourCellIdentifier") as! YourTableViewCell

    if (self.indexArray?.contains(indexPath as NSIndexPath))!
    {
        cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
    }
    else
    {
        cell.accessoryType  = .none
    }
    return cell
}
```